# Constructing text based adventure with php using an online tutorial but unable to test on xampp cli because of mysterious file path error

Tags: php, xml, xampp

I am trying to build a text based adventure game from this online tutorial below but am at "pulling my hair out" stage. I have looked up the error message I get on my cli on here but nothing is helping and some things I do not understand as am beginner.

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/21/4/2

I am on page two and am using xampp and shell to access the CLI on my windows pc.
I have entered this command on the shell command line prompt window: "php htdocs\textGame\game.php and previously php htdocs\textGame\gameworld.xml" which is where my files are kept as I didn't understand the following paragraph in the tutorial, where I got stuck:

"Before we go through that script line by line, first try running it. The commands are "north", "south", "west", and "east" for directions, "look" to repeat the description of the current place, and "quit" to exit the game. Run the game using the CLI SAPI, like this:

```
// Windows
copy game.php c:\php\cli
copy gameworld.xml c:\php\cli
cd c:\php\cli
php game.php
```

// Unix
php game.php
The extra instructions for Windows are there because you probably do not have the PHP CLI executable in your path, so we copy game.php and gameworld.xml into the same directory as the PHP CLI and run it from there. You should, of course, change "c:\php" to wherever you have PHP installed.

If all has worked well, you should be able to play the game - or at least as much of the game as we have so far!"

It hasn't, I get the following error:

```
"warning: simplexml_load file():I/O warning : failed to load external entity "gameworld.xml" in C:\xampp\htdocs\textGame\game.php on line 2"
followed by 
"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\textGame\game.php on line 10 to 12 and line 17 to 34".
```

I have checked my code and it is identical to that on the tutorial except I have changed room names and descriptions. I have also just 6 rooms as opposed to 8. The exits in my XML are the same and the php file is identical. Could this be a problem? The error message says that my path is wrong but have tried all variations.
Please help, I am really at a dead end and considering abandoning for another tutorial but this was the most helpful I had found so far.

Here are the two pages:
gameworld.xml

```
<WORLD>
    <ROOM>
        <NAME>The Government Room</NAME>
        <DESC>A room for the group of people with the authority to govern a country or state; a particular ministry in office.</DESC>
        <NORTH>1</NORTH>
        <SOUTH>2</SOUTH>
        <WEST>3</WEST>
        <EAST>4</EAST>
    </ROOM>

    <ROOM>
        <NAME>Your Room</NAME>
        <DESC>This is your private room.</DESC>
          <NORTH>-</NORTH>
        <SOUTH>0</SOUTH>
        <WEST>6</WEST>
        <EAST>7</EAST>
    </ROOM>




       <ROOM>
        <NAME>The Business Room</NAME>
        <DESC>A room for people of a regular occupation, profession, or trade that engages or wants to engage in "for profit" commercial activity.</DESC>
        <NORTH>0</NORTH>
        <SOUTH>5</SOUTH>
        <WEST>-</WEST>
        <EAST>-</EAST>
    </ROOM>


    <ROOM>
        <NAME>The Charity Room</NAME>
        <DESC>A room for charitable organizations that center on strictly non-profit and philanthropic goals as well as social well-being. </DESC>
        <NORTH>6</NORTH>
        <SOUTH>-</SOUTH>
        <WEST>-</WEST>
        <EAST>0</EAST>
    </ROOM>


         <ROOM>
        <NAME>The Organisation Room</NAME>
        <DESC>A room for an organized group of people with a particular purpose of organizing something which is primarily about social well-being and not solely for profit.</DESC>
        <NORTH>7</NORTH>
        <SOUTH>-</SOUTH>
        <WEST>0</WEST>
        <EAST>-</EAST>
    </ROOM>



    <ROOM>
        <NAME>The Individual Room</NAME>
        <DESC>A room of, or for, particular people. A room for a single human being as distinct from a group.</DESC>
        <NORTH>6</NORTH>
        <SOUTH>-</SOUTH>
        <WEST>-</WEST>
        <EAST>0</EAST>
    </ROOM>



    <ROOM>
        <NAME>The Academia Room</NAME>
        <DESC>The city walls are eight metres high and two thick, and have kept invaders out for centuries.</DESC>
        <NORTH>7</NORTH>
        <SOUTH>-</SOUTH>
        <WEST>0</WEST>
        <EAST>-</EAST>
    </ROOM>




</WORLD>
```

and 
game.php

```
<?php
    $World = simplexml_load_file("file:///gameworld.xml");
    $CurrentPos = 0;
    $Done = 0;
    print "\n";
    printplace() ;

    function printplace() {
        GLOBAL $World, $CurrentPos;
        $Room = $World->ROOM[$CurrentPos];
        $Name = $Room->NAME;
        $Desc = wordwrap((string)$Room->DESC);
        print "$Name\n";
        print str_repeat('-', strlen($Name));
        print "\n$Desc\n\n";

        if ((string)$Room->NORTH != '-') {
            $index = (int)$Room->NORTH;
            print "North: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}\n";
        }

        if ((string)$Room->SOUTH != '-') {
            $index = (int)$Room->SOUTH;
            print "South: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}\n";
        }

        if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
            $index = (int)$Room->WEST;
            print "West: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}\n";
        }

        if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
            $index = (int)$Room->EAST;
            print "East: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}\n";
        }

        print "\n";
    }

    while (!$Done) {
        $input = fgets(STDIN);
        print "\n"; // add another line break after the user input

        $input = split(' ', $input);

        switch(trim($input[0])) {
            case 'north':
                if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH != '-') {
                    $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH;
                    printplace() ;
                } else {
                    print "You cannot go north!\n";
                }
                break;
            case 'south':
                if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH != '-') {
                    $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH;
                    printplace() ;
                } else {
                    print "You cannot go south!\n";
                }
                break;
            case 'west':
                if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
                    $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST;
                    printplace() ;
                } else {
                    print "You cannot go west!\n";
                }
                break;
            case 'east':
                if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
                    $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST;
                    printplace() ;
                } else {
                    print "You cannot go east!\n";
                }
                break;
            case 'look':
                printplace() ;
                break;
            case 'quit':
                $Done = 1;
                break;
        }
    }

    print "\nThanks for playing!\n\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you gave, you `cd` to and copy the xml to `c:\php\cli`

But the game.php is running in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\textGame\game.php
```

Put the xml and run it there.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try but tbh I cannot find c:\php\cli on my pc

Comment: You went there in your question where it says "Run the game using the CLI SAPI, like this:"
or were just pasting all of that.

Comment: Regardless, like I said, just make sure `C:\xampp\htdocs\textGame\gameworld.xml` is there.

Comment: Hi, Thank you still I am unsuccesful. I typed this command into my cli:"copy game.php c:\php\cli
copy gameworld.xml c:\php\cli
cd c:\php\cli
php game.php"

Comment: As this gave me an error" the system cannot find file specified", I typed the following"copy game.php c:\xampp\php\cli
copy gameworld.xml c:\php\cli
cd c:\xampp\php\cli
php game.php" with same result

Comment: Do you have a file called gameworld.xml? Find it. Copy it. Paste it into `C:\xampp\htdocs\textGame\`. You can use windows explorer if you want.

Comment: yes, that file is already there along with game.php. So, any ideas of what i could try next?

Comment: It could be a permissions issue, check the xml file and make sure it can be read by the xampp user (make it readable by everybody just to check)

Comment: where do i check file permissions please? in notepad++? I have altered these before on filezila but only on remote server

Comment: Under Properties, Security, To change permissions, click Edit, Edit. FULL CONTROL, allow is unchecked...is that correct?

Comment: I feel like you might be in over your head at this point. You are trying to mess with the spark plugs in a car, but you don't yet know how to drive a car. Learn how to move, copy files, alter permissions, and how to google answers when you don't know them. THEN try to do  php on top of it.

Comment: I am sorry i keyboard have a glitch that types 3's like if I am holding key down so could n3ot aner3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333

Comment: 33333333333333333I AM NOT IN OVER MY HEAD3333.3 sorry, it has a simp3le solut3i3on. 33333

Comment: I have also "google"ed extensibly. But thanks anyway.

Comment: P.S. I have a foundation degree in computing.

Comment: Hey it is fixed. I wasn't a permissions issue. It was a settings issue. The environmental variable needed to be set. Thanks for trying to help.http://i.justrealized.com/2009/how-to-run-xampps-php-cli-and-cakephp-console/

Comment: Nice job! Way to stick with it. So many issues are just a matter of poking at it from every possible angle.